# Android - where are videos taken from intent stored?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

Let's say I have a method inside my activity that looks like this:

```
    private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

Then if everything works out fine, I access the taken video by its URI:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUri = intent.getData();
            // process video
        }
    }
```

Where does the video actually reside at this point? Is it temporarily stored in memory or does it get saved to permanent storage?

If I want my app to reliably access that video at some later point, what's the best way to go about this? Do I have to copy the video to my app's storage folder(s)?

Answer (score 1):

> Where does the video actually reside at this point?

It will reside wherever the user's camera app elects to put it. There are hundreds of different camera apps, both pre-installed by manufacturers and user-installed from the Play Store or elsewhere.

> Is it temporarily stored in memory or does it get saved to permanent storage?

That is up to the camera app.

> If I want my app to reliably access that video at some later point, what's the best way to go about this?

You can try passing a `content` `Uri` value [via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore#action_video_capture) as an extra on your `Intent`. You can use `FileProvider` to get that `Uri`, pointing to some file in a location that you control (e.g., `getFilesDir()` on `Context`). Most camera apps should honor this extra, but not all will.

Or, you could copy the video, as you suggest.

Or, you could use a camera library (e.g., FotoApparat, CameraKit-Android) and record the video within your own app.